# Array keeps writing to 0 index

Tags: php, arrays

I'm making a super basic diary program for class where the user inputs text into a form and when they hit submit, the page displays their most recent posts with the most recent at the top and the oldest toward the bottom.

When I try to add new entries to my array, whether I use []= or array_push, the array keeps writing to the 0 index of the array and I cannot figure out why. I haven't been able to find anything relevant online and I've been wracking my brain for several hours over this. Does anybody have any thoughts?

(I also realize that this is a very lame program, but this is just an assignment that's intended to be a brief introduction to PHP.)

```
<form action="<?print($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])?>" method="get">
    <textarea style="margin:auto;" rows="10" cols="50" name="diaryentry"></textarea>
    <input style="margin:auto;" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<?php
    if(!isset($_SESSION['entries']))
        $_SESSION['entries'] = array();

    $entries = array();
    $entries = &$_SESSION['entries'];
    $entries []= htmlentities(&$diaryentry);

    $reversed = array_reverse($entries, true);
?>

<p><?php 
     foreach($reversed as $entry){
     echo $entry . "<br>";
     }?>
</p>
```

Comment: `session_start();` loaded? I don't see it. If it isn't, load it.

Comment: When I add it, I get an error:

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent

Comment: They're sent the microsecond you output anything. Your first 4 lines consist of output. So you have to put the `session_start()` at the TOP of your file.

Comment: Place your HTML form below your PHP, then it should be OK. @user3439966 You don't have a choice loading `session_start();` since you are using sessions; it's required. `<?php session_start(); // rest of code ?>` ... HTML form.

Comment: Or leave it the way you have it now, just put `<?php session_start(); ?>` then the rest of your code below that. @user3439966

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
    if(!isset($_SESSION['entries']))
        $_SESSION['entries'] = array();

    $_SESSION['entries'][] = htmlentities($_POST['diaryentry']);

    $reversed = array_reverse($_SESSION['entries'], true);
?>
```

Previously there seems to be a lot of unnecessary variable assignment.

Answer (score 0):

It's standard behaviour.

If there is no `$array[0]` it will start writing it there, regardless of other indices it might contain. If it contains `$array[0]` and `$array[1]` it will continue writing at `$array[2]`. Basically it starts writing at [0] and continues on down the road (even if `$array['a']` and `$array['b']` exist).

On a sidenote, don't use the reference-operator `&` unless you know very well what it does and why you're using it. Right now it's completely useless. Using it can (and likely will) lead to bugs in your code which are very difficult to track down. Usage of `&` is very rarely required.

Comment: Sorry, I left the ampersands in because I was desperately flailing trying to get my code to work. Those should not be there.

The issue is that it is <i>always</i> writing at $array[0], and never writes at a higher index when it is supposed to be pushing new entries into the array.

Answer (score 0):

As has been mentioned in comments, you are using `$_SESSION` variables but you haven't called `session_start()`. As you discovered, `session_stert` will not work unless it is called before ANY kind of output is sent to the browser.

So, begin your file with `<?php session_start(); ?>` and you should be in business.

As an aside, consider using `<form action="" method="post">` - it's a more reliable way to post back to the same URL. This is especially useful when you discover "pretty" URLs.

Comment: I keep getting an error no matter where I put session_start().

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent and Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you put it *right* at the beginning, before ANYTHING else?

Comment: Oops, just got it at the very top. Not getting errors, but it's still writing to the $entries[0] every time.